# Natural numbers as (nodes of) a graph

Tags: graph-theory, natural-numbers

Is there a branch of mathematics that studies and classifies (infinite) graphs where nodes are natural numbers and edges represent some relationship between them?

A few examples I found:

*"...vertices are the natural numbers, with an edge between j and k if j∣k."* in 
[a question about definition of graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429536/a-question-about-definition-of-graph/1429556#1429556).

*"...two vertices being connected if the sum of the numbers on the two vertices add up to a prime number."* in [Proving that a "prime graph" is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457586/proving-that-a-prime-graph-is-connected).

If the Collatz conjecture is true, that relationship also organises natural numbers into a graph: https://www.jasondavies.com/collatz-graph/

Comment: If $(\mathbb{N},E)$ is an infinite graph where nodes are natural numbers then this graph defines a relation on $\mathbb{N}$: $n_1\sim n_2 \iff (n_1,n_2)\in E$. So you question is not clear.

Comment: I don't think that these problems are sufficiently similar for there to be a branch of mathematics that studies all of them together. They are merely applications of graph theory to answering questions about the natural numbers.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Fair enough. If you post this as an answer, I can accept that.